# Properly using "require" with node.js files

Tags: node.js

I have existing directories of a node project (my first one). And now I need to add this twitter library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/twitter

However, I'm not sure where to incorporate everything. I have a file at the top of my directory with a bunch of other `require` statements, but I can't seem to get the proper syntax, so my code fails and I can't start my app. Here's the code I'm trying to incorporate:

```
var Twitter = require('twitter');

var client = new Twitter({
 consumer_key: '',
  consumer_secret: '',
 access_token_key: '',
 access_token_secret: ''
});

var params = {screen_name: 'nodejs'};
client.get('statuses/user_timeline', params, function(error, tweets, response)     {
 if (!error) {
console.log(tweets);
}
});
```

If I put this in with the rest of my javascript files, I get errors that `require` is not a function. So, where does this statement go and where does the `twitter.js` file go?

Comment: `npm install twitter` did you install the node_module you are requiring?

Comment: I use gulp and yeoman generators to assist in setting up node projects. If you aren't sure why you don't have require as a function (maybe you are new to this like me) then I would suggest using a yeoman template to start off with as this will be only the beginning of your pain. You can learn the ins and outs as you go along. IMHO

Comment: @corn3lius, the error seems to be that "require is not a function" so I don't think that installing the lib will help. Basically his app doesn't know how to load the 'require' function as I understand it.

Comment: @corn3lius I did this install and it added a new directory called `node_modules`. I had the required files before but didn't do this part. So, now I'm not sure how to "point" to the right require file in the right location.

Comment: how are you running your app? can you add the exact error you get from the console when starting your app.

Comment: Are you running your app from the same directory where your package.json resides?

Comment: @teroi No...I actually have two different package.json files. Should I combine these? What's the right way to merge them together?

Comment: @corn3lius The app runs on IBM Bluemix. I'm using one of their libraries/code (https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/personality-insights-nodejs). Now I'm trying to add in some of my own code, but having an issue combining it together.